# Are these coaxial power barrel male jacks compatible with this female coaxial power barrel plug?

Tags: dc, connector, power-connector

I am going to design a PCB that shall contain a coaxial power barrel adapter for power. It will eventually connect with an external power supply like the one we often use with laptop and other equipment.

I have this adapter:

[image]

{The description is wrong: that is not a jack, it is a plug.}

The specification for this says "Fits 2.1 mm sockets" and "Barrel length: 12mm".

Does this mean that I must have a barrel that has pin diameter of 2.1mm that can exactly fit into this socket? Now what about the length of the barrel?

I have found this two coax power barrel PCB jacks:

[image]

They are both specified as having 2.1 mm pin diameter. Are they both compatible with this coax power barrel adapter with screw terminals which has 12 mm barrel length?

I was expecting there to be a variety of the connector with screw terminals containing different sized hole and barrel. However, it seems that is not the case. This screw terminal connector is perhaps designed for some other specific usage but I can use it for my purpose and get away with it.

Comment: I would select the supply that you plan to use long-term and find a PCB mounted connector to suit. It doesn't matter if you use a longer barrel for development and testing, it'll just stick out a bit.

Comment: Insufficient information: you need also the diameter of the pin. If those vendors do not specify it, buy from a reputable vendor instead, a vendor that provides complete spec sheets.

Comment: For what it's worth, I looked up barrel connectors with an inner diameter of 2.1 mm on Digi-Key, and the vast majority (150 out of 159) have an outer diameter of 5.5 mm.

Comment: I am a bit confused here, isn't it that as long as the external connector has a hole that fits the pin in the PCB connector, there is nothing more to be done? Do you mean that I need a connector pair whereby the pin and pin hole diameter matches and the barrel and barrel hole diameter also matches?

Comment: For a 2.1mm pin to fit, the aperture it goes into must be greater than 2.1mm; that's only a NOMINAL size specification.   For best satisfaction, either buy a variety of likely connectors OR try to find a mated pair.